# Vba + Google Chrome

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, google-chrome

Estou com dúvidas há algum tempo e mesmo após várias pesquisas não obtive sucesso.
Estou criando uma função no VBA capaz de manipular uma página da internet utilizando o Google Chrome. Apesar de setar o chrome como objeto só consigo enviar comandos "sendkeys" para o navegador e isso é complicado, pois não consigo capturar informações mas somente enviar as funções do teclado.
Minha pergunta é: Há alguma forma de utilizar o vba para capturar/enviar/manipular as páginas abertas no google chrome sem utilizar métodos sendkeys?

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente o VBA não consegue interagir com estes softwares nativamente, somente com o Internet Explorer (IE).

Portanto, recomendo a utilização de um *3rd party*:

## [Selenium VBA](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/)