# É possível puxar informações de um local específico em um site no excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

a minha dúvida é a seguinte...
Eu tenho um TopDesk de chamados.
Gostaria de puxar informações como data de abertura e conclusão e status (aberto, fechado, resolvido)...
Queria saber se no excel tem como eu fazer esse procedimento.

É o mesmo conceito que utilizamos com o selenium em python pra fazer isso.
Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao colocar o ID, ele puxar o status, a data de abertura, etc...
Puxar no html < li > alguma coisa etc...

Comment: Isso pode ser realizado pelo Selenium no Python e depois inserir os dados no Excel, ou criar um CSV e importar pelo Excel. Ou utilizar o [Selenium VBA](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/). Veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280223/75104)

Answer (score 0):

Sim, usando VBA no Excel. (Caso não conheça, comente que eu explico bem mais detalhado como ativa-lo e usar os comandos)

Crie uma Form, depois um botão.

Clique em Ferramentas e depois em Referencias e ative as seguintes opções "Microsoft Html Object Library" e "Microsoft xml".

Agora dê um duplo clique no botão e insira o seguinte código:

```
'Iniciando variaveis
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim source As Object

With http
     'Open(método, url, usuario(se necessario), senha(se necessario))
    .Open "GET", "http://www.brazil4export.com/en/pesquisa/resultado/?page=1&", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
'Um loop para pegar informações de um elemento
For Each source In html.getElementsByClassName("panel-heading")
    x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = source.getAttribute("data-Name")
    Cells(x, 2) = source.getAttribute("data-site")
Next source
```

Agora é só estudar esse código e molda-lo para suas necessidades. Teste ele assim e veja funcionando.